# find_last_of not working for xml strings

Tags: c++, xml

I have templated xml as shown below in which i need to find last ChildTag xml string.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<Test xmlns:Test="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
<TestID>1</TestID>
<TestData>
<ParentTag1>A</ParentTag1>
<ParentTag2>B</ParentTag2>
{{ChildTag}}
</TestData>
</Test>
ChildTag
<Tag1>E</Tag1>
<Tag2>F</Tag2>
```

So the approach i followed is find last of ChildTag in that string and take substring from that position. Below is the sample code for this and it should be noted that I am reading this xml from file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin("abc.xml");
    fin.unsetf(ios_base::skipws);
    std::string fileData = std::string(std::istream_iterator<char>(fin),std::istream_iterator<char>());
    std::cout<<fileData<<std::endl;
    auto childxmlindex = fileData.find_last_of("ChildTag");
    std::cout<<childxmlindex<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Child XML : "<<fileData.substr(childxmlindex)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Issue is with the line fileData.find_last_of("ChildTag") because it is giving random number nothing to do with actual index.Is there any issue with this string that is causing find_last_of to fail ?

Comment: complete code is at location https://repl.it/repls/PureAptMoto

Comment: Is the result random or equal to `std::string::npos`?

Comment: result is random and not std::string::npos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expectation of `find_last_of` is wrong:

> Searches the string for the last character that matches any of the characters specified in its arguments

So `fileData.find_last_of("ChildTag");` return the position matching of the letter `'C'`, `'h'`, `'i'`, `'l'`, `'d'`, `'T'`, `'a'`, `'g'`. `'g'` in your case.

Your are looking for `rfind`.